# Calling class that initiates UI class in python

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, qt-creator

I have an issue while creating my small Python project. I am used to Java and this is still quite new to me. 
The problem is i create a UI class from QtCreator. Then convert it to `.py` and import to my project. I have a class that for now is considered `main` that initiates and runs the UI class. The problem is i need to have a class that is really the `main` class and when app is started this class to call the second class that initiates the UI. 
To sum it up now when app is started i have `A > calls > B(UI)`. 
I need it to be `A > calls > B > init > C(UI)`.
Is that possible? My idea is that B must be only a manager class that sets up the UI and run it. 
Here is my working code so far:
1.Manager class-

```
class mainpanelManager(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = mainpanelManager()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and UI class is typical UI generated class. I will post only constructor:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
```

In this case `mainpaneManager` runs `Ui_MainWindow` after element initiation.
I want to have a 3rd class that calls `mainpanelManager`. 
What do i do with this `__name__` function? Move it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure I understand what you're asking for, but it would seem to be as simple as this:

```
class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = MainPanelManager()
        self.window.show()             

class MainPanelManager(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.settingsButton.clicked.connect(self.editSettings)
        self.loadSettings()

    def editSettings(self):
        dialog = SettingsDialog(self)
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            self.loadSettings()

    def loadSettings(self):
        # do stuff to load settings...

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ill give it a try. Thanks for understanding. Im having a huge problem understanding class calling in python. I did quite more complex stuff but i cant seems to understand how to do just `Myclass myclass = new Myclass(); myclass.setVisible(true)` in python...

Comment: Ok this worked also. My last problem is probably quite simple. I want to open small window(maybe dialog) with settings when "settings" button is clicked. Function will be set in `MainPanelManager` after after `setupUI`. Will the constructor of the class change? How to do that. I promise its the last one. I just fail to find that info  up to date. I was almost at the edge of quitting python...

Comment: @nephilimrising. I've updated my code example to give you the basics. You might want to try [Python For Java Programmers](http://python4java.necaiseweb.org/Main/TableOfContents) and [Python Is Not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) before writing any more code, though.

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort!